# Как вывести все изображение из папки drawable

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview, android-imageview

Добрый день!

В Andorid Studio в папке drawable лежат фото, для удобства я их засунул в массивы. Необходимо вывести данные из массива на Scroling activity. Как это можно сделать?

```
int[] Arr1 = {R.drawable.S_1,R.drawable.S_2,R.drawable.S_3,R.drawable.S_4};
int[] Arr2 = {R.drawable.S_21,R.drawable.S_12,R.drawable.S_13,R.drawable.S_14};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Пробегайтесь циклом по массиву.
2. В каждой итерации добавляете `ImageView` в единственного ребёнка `ScrollView` и назначайте ему картинку.
3. После завершения цикла и вызова `onResume` метода активити получите `OutOfMemoryError`
4. Осознайте, что много картинок в `ScrollView` сжирают всю память.
5. Поймите, что картинки надо в списке отображать.
6. Попробуйте сделать это через устаревший `ListView`
7. Поимейте множество проблем с ним.
8. Пересильте себя и перепишите всё под `RecyclerView`
9. ???
10. Profit!